# Query over the resistivity of diamond

Tags: electrical-resistance, material-science, semiconductor-physics, diamond

In Griffths' book *Introduction to Electrodynamics* he includes diamond as a semiconductor and quotes a value of resistivity of $\rho = 2.7 \,\,\, \Omega m$. Surely  this is a mistake? Where does this number come from?

Comment: Rather than answer my question I note the following reference: https://hypertextbook.com/facts/2004/KerryRemulla.shtml                                                                            "There are four diamond types: type Ia, Ib, IIa, and IIb.Type Ia, Ib, and IIa usually have a resisttivity $1 \times 10^{18} \,\, \Omega m$.Type IIb has a resistivity of $1-10^5 \,\, \Omega m$.They are natural diamonds, but Type IIa is the purest one." The reference to 2.7 $\Omega m$ is apparently dues to Lide, David R. Handbook of Chemistry and Physics, 75th Edition. Boca Raton, FL: CRC Press, 1985.

Answer (score 0):

There are several types of diamond. The majority are excellent electrical insulators, with resistivities of the order of $10^{16} \ \Omega m$. However some natural diamonds (particularly type IIb) are p-type semiconductors due to doping with boron impurities, and can have substantially lower resistivities as a result. Presumably this is the case that Griffiths is considering.

Comment: Curiously, diamond is a good conductor of heat, despite (pure) diamond being a poor conductor of electricity. But that's a topic for another question. ;)

Comment: And isotopically pure diamond is even better, giving a big hint as to why it is so good...